# SharePoint 2013 my site takes longer time to load

Tags: performance, mysite

I've implemented the spswakeup powershell script on the environment to make the first visit of the SharePoint environment a bit less painfull (spswakeup.codeplex.com). This is really a solution to load my SharePoint intranet faster, even if the first user visits the SharePoint.

The issue is now that at random times, the My site still takes 15-30 seconds to load, even if these are in the spswakeup script too (visits all sites and site collections in the web applications).

My feeling (but I can be wrong) is that this mysite takes longer due to a connection to the Active Directory or something like that. Is there a tool or a way to test this? Or does anyone know what else this can be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the ULS/Event Logs for issues of any kind, but especially with object caching and Distributed Cache. These may really bring down performance when incorrectly configured.

Is the server showing obvious bottlenecks (CPU/RAM) ?

Comment: Also check for application pool recycling as that will cause the wake up effect to be lost.